# Perl Sorting Hash by Value of Value

Tags: sorting, perl, hash

I have a hash that looks like

```
'Jarrod' => {
                                'Age' => '25 ',
                                'Occupation' => Student
                              },
'Elizabeth' => {
                                'Age' => '18',
                                'Occupation' => Student
                                },
'Nick' => {
                                'Age' => '32 ',
                                'Occupation' => Lawyer
                               },
```

I am trying to sort them by age so it will look like

```
'Nick' => {
                                'Age' => '32 ',
                                'Occupation' => Lawyer
                               },
'Jarrod' => {
                                'Age' => '25 ',
                                'Occupation' => Student
                              },
'Elizabeth' => {
                                'Age' => '18',
                                'Occupation' => Student
                                },
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to access anything past Age. How can I access the value of a value when ordering hash keys?

Comment: You can't sort hashes, hashes are unordered. Not unless you use some additional software. If you want order, use an array.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to do exactly. Are you trying to sort the names according to their age?

Comment: @TLP Yes, ordering name by age

Comment: What you intend to do with the sorted values determines the next step from here.

Comment: The [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) "Data Structures Cookbook" is a handy read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hash variable `%h` with the shown data can be processed in the desired order as

```
use Data::Dump qw(pp);  # to print out a complex data structure

say "$_->[0] => ", pp($_) for 
    map { [ $_, $h{$_} ] } 
        sort { $h{$b}->{Age} <=> $h{$a}->{Age} } 
             keys %h;
```

what prints (from a complete program below)

```
Nick => { Age => "32 ", Occupation => "Lawyer" }
Jarrod => { Age => "25 ", Occupation => "Student" }
Elizabeth => { Age => 18, Occupation => "Student" }
```

Note though that we cannot "sort a hash" and then have it be that way, as hashes are inherently random with order.<sup>†</sup>  But we can of course go through and process the elements in a particular order, as above for example.

Explanation: [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort) takes pairs of elements of a submitted list in turn, available in variables `$a` and `$b`, and then runs the block of code we provide, so to [compare](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Equality-Operators) them as prescribed. Here we have it compare, and thus sort, the elements by the value at key `Age`.

The output, though, is just those keys sorted as such!  So we then pass that through a `map`, which combines each key with its hashref value and returns those pairs, each in an arrayref.  That is used to print them, as a place holder for the actual processing.

A complete program

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd pp);

my %h = ( 
    'Jarrod' => {
        'Age' => '25 ',
        'Occupation' => 'Student'
    },  
    'Elizabeth' => {
        'Age' => '18',
        'Occupation' => 'Student'
    },  
    'Nick' => {
        'Age' => '32 ',
        'Occupation' => 'Lawyer'
    },  
);

say "$_->[0] => ", pp($_->[1]) for 
    map { [ $_, $h{$_} ] } sort { $h{$b}->{Age} <=> $h{$a}->{Age} } keys %h;
```

Or, for a workable template, change to something like

```
my @sorted_pairs = 
    map { [ $_, $h{$_} ] } sort { $h{$b}->{Age} <=> $h{$a}->{Age} } keys %h;

for my $key_data (@sorted_pairs) {
    say $key_data->[0], ' => ', pp $key_data->[1];  # or just: dd $key_data;

    # my ($name, $data) = @$key_data;
    # Process $data (a hashref) for each $name
}
```

Once we start building more suitable data structures for ordered data then there are various options, including one-person hashrefs for each name, stored in an array in the right order.  Ultimately, all that can be very nicely organized in a class.

---

Note how [Sort::Key](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key) makes the sorting part considerably less cumbersome

```
use Sort::Key qw(rnkeysort);  # rn... -> Reverse Numerical

my @pairs = map { [ $_, $h{$_} ] } rnkeysort { $h{$_}->{Age} } keys %h;
```

The more complex -- or specific -- the sorting the more benefit from this module, with its many specific functions for generic criteria.

If these ages are given as integers then there is `ikeysort` (and `rikeysort`) and then those are hopefully unsigned integers, for which there is `ukeysort` (and `rukeysort`).

---

<sup>†</sup>   See [keys](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys) and [perlsec](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks), for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can't sort a hash. A hash's elements are inherently unordered.

---

If you just want to visit the elements of hash in order, you can do that by getting and sorting the keys.

```perl
for my $name (
   sort { $people{ $b }{ age } <=> $people{ $a }{ age } }
      keys( %people ) 
) {
   my $person = $people{ $name };
   ...
}
```

or

```perl
use Sort::Key qw( rikeysort );

for my $name (
   rikeysort { $people{ $_ }{ age } }
      keys( %people ) 
) {
   my $person = $people{ $name };
   ...
}
```

---

If you need an ordered structure, you could start by converting the data to an array of people.

```perl
my @unordered_people =
   map { +{ name => $_, %{ $people{ $_ } } }
      keys( %people );
```

Then sorting that.

```perl
my @ordered_people =
   sort { $b->{ age } <=> $a->{ age } }
      @unordered_people;
```

or

```perl
use Sort::Key qw( rikeysort );

my @ordered_people =
   rikeysort { $_->{ age } }
      @unordered_people;
```